# Add editable form fields to document in Docusign

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am sending contracts from Sf using Docusign apis. There is information table in the document. I need to add editable form fields to document, so that the recipient can edit them to correct the information. Also I need to sense the changes made by recipient. Is this possible? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The functionality exists and it's called Merge Fields:

https://www.docusign.com/support/salesforce/documentation/dfs-user-guide/user-guide/create-merge-fields-user

Hope this helps